# using react-native version: 0.22.2 app getting crashes in RCTSRWebSocket

Tags: react-native

Hai i am using native latest version 0.22.2, here my app is crashes and shows like this

[image]

here is the code which i wrote in index.ios.js:

```
var QRreader = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            text: 'http://facebook.github.io/react-native/',
            record:{"name":"hussian","place":"vskp","age":"23"}
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
                <QRCode
                    value={this.state.text}
                    size={200}
                    bgColor='red'
                    fgColor='white'/>
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

can any one give me suggestions that what is the problem and how to resolve it, Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add &dev=false to the url link to your js bundle, such as:
"http://localhost:8081/start.index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=false"

This issue was reported here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5198